# Why did Morton want the McBain farm?

Tags: once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

In [*Once Upon a Time in the West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_the_West) (1968), Morton is obsessed with reaching the Pacific as quickly as possible, and has hired Frank to clear any small problems along the way. This includes “scaring” McBain.

But McBain wants to build a station and a whole town for the railroad. This seems like it would be to Morton’s advantage. He had a contract on file and everything.

Why was McBain considered an obstacle to Morton?

Comment: Maybe Morton didn't want to wait for a station etc. to be built? He just wanted to get the track laid quickly, not laid well.

Comment: Yeah, that whole plot doesn't make sense. Morton could always have used the power of government to apply eminent domain to obtain the land (like this happened in real life).

Comment: Then again, this movie is a parable, a movie about movies, where the lead characters are tropes from old(er) westerns and story elements as well as locations refer to other westerns. It is about how the modern era (trains etc.) is killing off the "wild west" and its characters (the gunslingers, ...). The plot is a mere means to an end.

Comment: @BCdotWEB You could have just said "It's Italian". ;) One answer I've considered is it's part of the movie deliberately muddying classic good guy/bad guy tropes, but I don't really see how.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Technically, Eminent Domain could not have been used, not even in reality. The government wasn't building the railroads, companies were. If one of the companies wanted to go through land owned by someone, they had to buy it, or force/scare the owners off. For a (kinda sorta, if you squint real hard) look into the (completely dramatized) reality of building the first railroad, watch "Hell on wheels" (tv series)

Comment: @CGCampbell  Actually if the local or higher government thinks that a private business like a railroad would be good for the community, it can use eminent domain to ascquire a property and give or sell it to that private enterprise.  There are sometimes complaints that local leaders are misusing eminnent domain for businesses without there being sufficient benefit to the community, in return for possible bribe sor campaign  donations.  I note that only four transcontinental railroads were built in the 19th century US west, and 3 were granted public land.  Continued.

Comment: Continued.  The 4th 19th century trancontinenatl railroad, the Great Northern Railway, bought land from the US government and sold it to setters attracted by the ralroad.  I assume that all westerns railroads had to buy land from private owners sometimes at terminal cities, so I guess there was always the chance they would have a local governmentuse eminent domain or instead do someting criminal.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Understand and agree. Ironically, I will point out that one of the first-ish uses of ED was *United States v. Gettysburg Electric Railroad Company* where the government actually *took* land from a railroad (actually a trolley system) to keep it from establishing trolley lines on GBMA roads.

Comment: While the legal background is interesting, it's not relevant to the question. If the film involved legal complexities like Eminent Domain they would have brought it up.

Comment: Perhaps the point was that all the killing was pointless. Morton would have gotten what he wanted if he'd just left McBain alone, but that's not how men like Morton and Frank see the world.

Comment: Land rights is why it was worth embezzling, defrauding the government, and going to jail. *Right of way* is everything, and if you don't have all of it then you have nothing because then there can be competition. Definitely go watch *Hell on Wheels*. That's basically the plot, and it's rather historically accurate. "the government actually took land from a railroad" because at that time they were the second largest land holders after the Federal government.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go into my own speculation. Morton could have negotiated with McBain, found out he's eager to build a station, and worked to their mutual advantage. But that would go against the theme of the film. Negotiation, communication, and mutual benefit are never considered, never even raised. In Sergio Leone's westerns, problems are only solved by violence.

Sergio Leone's westerns were about subverting the black and white, good vs bad morality of American westerns. He presents the same basic stories, the same good vs bad framing, but the morality and motivations of his characters are more out of self-interest than "good". For example, in his "Dollars Trilogy", Clint Eastwood is presented as the "good guy". He's not particularly bad, but he's certainly not good. He's mostly in it for the money.

"Once Upon A Time In The West"'s "good guys" are all in it for themselves. Harmonica is not protecting Mrs. McBain, he uses her for revenge on Frank. Cheyenne, a murderous criminal, seems legitimately concerned for Mrs. McBain, but more out of boredom and curiosity than heroism. Once their interests are served, rather than riding off into the sunset, they abandon her.

The victims are the McBains. While their murder is heinous, the McBains are not presented as particularly sympathetic. Mr. McBain is in it for the money; for himself and his family. He's a harsh father who smacks his children and married a whore he hardly knows to raise them. Mrs. McBain, rather than a weeping widow, is literally a whore shown to be more concerned about her dead husband's money than her dead husband. She even considers forming a relationship with Frank, her husband's murderer, if that means saving herself.

Frank, the very bad guy, is a good looking, well dressed, smiling man. He's also a thug who kills children when it's convenient.

Morton, ostensibly Frank's boss, is a cripple barely able to control his underlings. Morton is obsessed with reaching the sea. His terminal illness is increasingly making him desperate, rushed, and willing to accept Frank's immoral methods as long as they solve his "little problems".

Harmonica, Cheyenne, Frank, Morton, and Mr. McBain all use violence and intimidation to solve their problems. Unlike the clean "good guy with a gun" ethos of American westerns, Sergio Leone's westerns show violence as brutal and amoral.

Morton needs McBain's land to build a station; McBain is in his way. We never hear about any attempts to negotiate with McBain, nor of McBain informing Morton about his intent to build a station. Instead, McBain keeps it a secret. That would require communication, mutual trust, and understanding. These all go against the theme of showing the nature of solving problems by violence: quick, brutal, decisive, efficient, and amoral violence.

Comment: So, to answer the question: Morton wanted the farmland because he didn't _know_ McBain was planning to build a station there?

Comment: @gidds Yes. Morton never thought to look into it, and McBain kept it secret.